# Read dictonary of a txt in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I saved some dictionaries in a .txt with:

```
# The form of store the data is in a dictionary of a dictionary
data = { "DNI": dni, "Nombre": name, "Apellido": surname, "Usuario": username, "Contraseña": password}
with open(dbUsers, "a+") as db:
    db.write("\n" + str(data))
    # Finally the program send a OK message and close the file
    db.close()
    print("El usuario y sus datos se han introducido correctamente.")
```

Now I'm trying to get the different lines (one line, one dictionary) of the `.txt` with:

```
with open(dbUsers, "r") as db:
    for line in db:
```

But that lines are not a dictionary so I can't get the different values with the keys. My question is: how can I convert the different lines (with a dictionary format) with a dictionary inside in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string to a dict.

```py
import ast
with open(dbUsers, "r") as db:
    for line in db:
        if not line.isspace():
            d = ast.literal_eval(line)
            print(d)
```

Comment: It's a JSON value - why not `json.load`?